# Proof by showing the interior of one set is the subset of another

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

My question is as follows:-

if $B \subseteq A, then, B^0 \subseteq A^0 $

My attempt shown below:-

if y $\in$ $B^0$
$\implies \exists ,\epsilon>0$
such that $B(x,\epsilon) \subset B$
$$since, y \in B(x,\epsilon) \subseteq B$$

$$\implies$$

$$y \in B$$

$$\therefore B^0 \subseteq B$$

since$$B \subseteq A$$
$$\implies B^0 \subseteq B \subseteq A$$

Therefore  $$B^0 \subseteq B \subseteq A^0 \subseteq A$$

Can anyone tell me if what I have done is correct and if not the necessary steps to take to prove the said question?

Comment: That's not correct, no. In particular, just because $U \subset W$ and $V \subset W$, that doesn't mean $U \subset V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overcomplicate this.

If $x\in B^\circ$, there is $\epsilon >0$ s.t. $B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq B$. Since $B\subseteq A$, we have $B(x,\epsilon) \subseteq A$ and thus $x\in A^\circ$.

Remark: Rewriting the proof with neighborhoods instead of open balls, the proof generalises to arbitrary topological spaces.

---

Your proof is also incorrect. You have written that $B \subseteq A^\circ$ which is seen to be false by taking $A = B = [0,1]$ with the usual metric.

Comment: i have just started metric spaces but ill take what you said into account thank you for the help and advice.

Comment: Nevermind my topology remark then. Metric spaces is a fun topic once you get past the definitions. Good luck!

Comment: ok so my last statement is inaccurate based on what your saying?

Comment: Yes $B\subseteq A \implies B\subseteq A^\circ$ is false. Take the metric space $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $A= B =[0,1]$. Then $A^\circ =]0,1[$ and you see that can't be correct.

Comment: ok i understand i was suppose to say that the point is a member of the interior of the set A as compared to just stating what i said i see the issue thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct, you have written that $B \subseteq A^°.$ In geneal, this is not true.

If $y\in B^°$ we get $ \epsilon >0$ such that $B(y,\epsilon) \subseteq B.$ Thus $B(y,\epsilon) \subseteq A.$ Hence $y$ is an interior point of $A$.

Comment: thanks @fred for the help greatly appreciated